# Sb admin 2 menu doesn't collapse when I edit some content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working to edit some content for this Bootstrap theme: http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/

When I delete some content from the index.html file the left side bar navigation menu has been expanded and didn't collapse again.

Here is the edited index.html code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>SB Admin 2 - Bootstrap Admin Theme</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- MetisMenu CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Timeline CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/timeline.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/sb-admin-2.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Morris Charts CSS -->
    <link href="css/plugins/morris.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

        <!-- Navigation -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">SB Admin v2.0</a>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <ul class="nav navbar-top-links navbar-right">                        
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-bell fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-alerts">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-comment fa-fw"></i> New Comment
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-fw"></i> 3 New Followers
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">12 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope fa-fw"></i> Message Sent
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-fw"></i> New Task
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <div>
                                    <i class="fa fa-upload fa-fw"></i> Server Rebooted
                                    <span class="pull-right text-muted small">4 minutes ago</span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="text-center" href="#">
                                <strong>See All Alerts</strong>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-alerts -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i>  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-user">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i> User Profile</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-gear fa-fw"></i> Settings</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="login.html"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i> Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.dropdown-user -->
                </li>
                <!-- /.dropdown -->
            </ul>
            <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li class="sidebar-search">
                            <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                                <span class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                                    <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </span>
                            </div>
                            <!-- /input-group -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a class="active" href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Charts<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Flot Charts</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Morris.js Charts</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-table fa-fw"></i> Tables</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-fw"></i> Forms</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-fw"></i> UI Elements<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Panels and Wells</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Buttons</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Notifications</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Typography</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Grid</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                        </li>
                     
                        </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
        </nav>

        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <h1 class="page-header">Dashboard</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-primary">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-comments fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge">26</div>
                                    <div>New Comments!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-green">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-tasks fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge">12</div>
                                    <div>New Tasks!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-yellow">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge">124</div>
                                    <div>New Orders!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6">
                    <div class="panel panel-red">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <i class="fa fa-support fa-5x"></i>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-9 text-right">
                                    <div class="huge">13</div>
                                    <div>Support Tickets!</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">
                            <div class="panel-footer">
                                <span class="pull-left">View Details</span>
                                <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i></span>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
            
            </div>
            <!-- /.row -->
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-wrapper -->

    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->

    <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/raphael.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your markup is correct and still works. (http://jsfiddle.net/skjbc2u8/) Are you sure every file is really available? Use your browser dev tools to check for 404 errors or any other js errors.

Comment: i didn't change anything yet, except the index.html file, that why this problem appear. image from my browser: http://im69.gulfup.com/eajprp.png

Comment: This doesn't help. I used the html you posted here in the fiddle and as you can see it works, so it must be some problem with the js files. Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: all js files has been placed correctly(i didn't do anything with them). i got this error in console: Error: Graph container element not found
http://127.0.0.1:8080/admin/sb-admin-2/sb-admin-2/js/plugins/morris/morris.min.js
Line 6

Comment: @WhiteOne have solved the problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to remove `<script src="js/plugins/morris/morris-data.js"></script>` from the bottom of your index.html.

This file contains sample data from the demo preview. Since you removed these graph `div` containers, the script throws an error as it can't find the container. This error stops the script execution and therefore the metis-menu script doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Thank you. couldn't figure out the problem

Comment: Just saved me HOURS of debug. Thank YOU!

Answer (score 2):

I almost went crazy.
Check the file sb-admin-2.js

end of the file:

```
var url = window.location;
var element = $('ul.nav a').filter(function() {
    return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
}).addClass('active').parent().parent().addClass('in').parent();
if (element.is('li')) {
    element.addClass('active');
```

commented only that part of the code
/* */

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer? What do you mean by commented out that part of the code?